# Error booting, /boot/efi not mounted

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, fstab

I have mutliples problems when booting my ubuntu. I think it's coming from when I installed the steam software, I noticed that my wifi symbol desapeared (a little detail for what's follow).
My ubuntu can't boot, I'm in emergency mode everytime I boot due to a time out caused by the (not mounting) of EFI (I guess).
`Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/96....`.
My `/etc/fstab` looks fine too, when I compare with the `blkid`.
In the emergency mode i don't think to have access to internet. When I use iwconfig I only get lo saying `no wireless extensions.` so I can't install anything from here to fix things.
My boot/efi folder is empty.
I don't really know what to do from these point beside reinstalling ubuntu.
My ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS.
Thank you for your help
[Boot emergency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLZ1s.jpg)
[Boot recovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv0II.jpg)

Comment: Are you dual booting with Windows? And then have either bitlocker or Windows fast startup on. Or some systems have a UEFI setting. Review UEFI settings as an UEFI update restores many settings to defaults. On one system I only have to make 1 or 2 changes and on another had to make many changes. I had to keep a list to make sure I corrected then all after an update.